# IE9 - 11 SVG backgrounds are blurry

Tags: image, css, internet-explorer, svg

This is only happening in Internet explorer. I am looking for a solution. I read that ie rasterizes background images or something just like older firefox versions but what are the solutions? Im so desperate. I dont want to serve an inline img image only because of IE.

This is seriously limiting. All other browsers render the SVG 99% the same and accurately.

Comment: I think you need to produce an example.

Comment: @Ian. The example is simple. A background SVG image with only background-size:100% and container width 100%. The position of the container is absolute and for the height I used padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inline image SVGs. If you are concerned that the resource is download by browsers other than IE then use javascript media queries

Answer (score 0):

I've found that deleting the width and height attributes of the svg root (in the svg file itself) helps a little, but not always. You will want to make sure viewBox is defined to retain the aspect ratio.